# Elasticsearch max bytes length exceeded exception

Tags: json, elasticsearch, exception

So.. from beginning.
I'm trying to create elasticsearch index with stemmer and synonyms filter but I ran into some problems.

I'm actually having problem with second part of my goal. I want to provide .txt file in order to define those synonyms, the trick is that file is kind of large (20-40MB) and elasticsearch is throwing max bytes length exceeded exception which fully looks like this:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to build synonyms"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to build synonyms",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "max_bytes_length_exceeded_exception",
      "reason" : "bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 135503"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Searching through internet for option to increase the limit was unfortunately... not efficient.
Is there any option to increase the limit? Or there is some kind of workaround for this situation?

Any idea matters, thanks.

//Edit
Whole index json

```
PUT test_index
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "german_keywords":{
               "type":"keyword_marker",
               "keywords":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "german_stemmer":{
               "type":"stemmer",
               "language":"german"
            },
            "german_synonym":{
               "type":"synonym",
               "synonyms_path":"analysis/export.txt"
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "german":{
               "tokenizer":"keyword",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "german_keywords",
                  "german_stemmer",
                  "german_synonym"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "fval":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "exact":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "analyzer":"german"
               }
            }
         },
         "sval":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "exact":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "analyzer":"german"
               }
            }
         },
         "tval":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "exact":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "analyzer":"german"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your mapping to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Here you go :) @saeednasehi